# How to get person who merged pull request via API

Tags: pull-request, bitbucket-server

We use branch permissions to restrict write access to develop and master. I'm interesting in auditing the work of some developers who have provisional write access and thus can approve pull requests, in the hopes to make their provisional access permanent. However, I'm having trouble getting the data I need. Our repository is busy, so I'd like to aggregate the data programatically.

I looked at the [Stash API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.3.0/stash-rest.html), and discovered that I can get the current status of a pull request via REST.

While I can see that the state is 'MERGED', it doesn't seem possible to find out who performed the merge. Is there a public API that exposes that data, or would I need to screen scrape the various pull request home pages to gather this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the activities endpoint to obtain the actions that occurred on a pull request. For a pull request that has been merged there will be an entry (amongst other activity) with

```
action: "MERGED"
```

and a user object corresponding to the user that did it.